# Website wordcount using WGET

Tags: wget, translation, word-count

I would like to know if it's possible to use wget to wordcount an entire website.

Has anyone already tried that?

This is what I have found so far:

```
wget -q -O- http://www.website.com | grep -c .
```

Comment: You mean actual word count? or do you want to count also the meta-words such as tags, attributes, titles etc?

Comment: yes just the content

Comment: Then you need to have an HTML parser that can process input from stdin. Don't know any ATM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wget -q -r -O- http://www.example.com | wc -l`

But if the site is not static, has password protected areas or contains forms, you are not going to be able to retrieve all of it easily.

If you need to count all the words on, say Amazon, you might need to top up the credit card associated with your one-click account :-)